# Summarizing a sub-group in R and calculating percentages

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm new to data wrangling in R and I have a dataset in that looks like this:

> | tag_id | color | number | total (red+blue) |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | red | 2 | 5 |
> | 1 | blue | 3 | 5 |
> | 2 | red | 5 | 7 |
> | 2 | blue | 2 | 7 |
> | 3 | red | 8 | 15 |
> | 3 | blue | 7 | 15 |
> | ... | ... | ... | ... |

There are many tag_ids and only two colors - red and blue.
I want to create a new float column pct_red which gives the % red for that specific tag_id. I want the dataset to look like:

> | tag_id | color | number | total(red+blue) | pct_red |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | red | 2 | 5 | 40.00.. |
> | 1 | blue | 3 | 5 | 40.00.. |
> | 2 | red | 5 | 7 | 71.42.. |
> | 2 | blue | 2 | 7 | 71.42.. |
> | 3 | red | 8 | 15 | 53.33.. |
> | 3 | blue | 7 | 15 | 53.33.. |
> | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I have tried doing variations of the following but I can't get it right:

`data %>% group_by(tag_id, color) %>% filter(color="red") %>% mutate(pct_red = number/total)`

Comment: In the future please use the `dput(your_data_object)` function to automatically print out code to the console that will allow us to rebuild your input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(tag_id) %>% 
       mutate(pct_red = 100*number[color == 'red']/`total (red+blue)`)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   tag_id [3]
  tag_id color number `total (red+blue)` pct_red
   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>              <dbl>   <dbl>
1      1 red        2                  5    40  
2      1 blue       3                  5    40  
3      2 red        5                  7    71.4
4      2 blue       2                  7    71.4
5      3 red        8                 15    53.3
6      3 blue       7                 15    53.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Karthik gives a fine example.

Here is an alternate approach that "pivots wider" such that the `number` column becomes two columns `RED` and `BLUE` and you have 1 row per `tag_id` rather than two rows per tag id with all of the totals and summary values duplicated.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

dat <- tribble(~tag_id, ~color,~number, ~total,
        1, "RED", 2, 5,
        1, "BLUE", 3, 5,
        2, "RED", 5, 7,
        2, "BLUE", 2, 7,
        3, "RED", 8, 15,
        3, "BLUE", 7, 15)

dat %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = color, values_from = number) %>% 
  group_by(tag_id) %>%
  mutate(pct_red = RED / total)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#> # Groups:   tag_id [3]
#>   tag_id total   RED  BLUE pct_red
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1      1     5     2     3   0.4  
#> 2      2     7     5     2   0.714
#> 3      3    15     8     7   0.533
```